# How to redirect/rewrite directory to another on subdomain?

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-301

I am trying to rewrite urls of a domain.

`www.example.com/dir1/` to `www.example.com/dir2/`

and

`sub1.example.com/dir1/` to `sub1.example.com/dir2/`

Problem is sub1 is a WordPress multisite sharing the same htaccess with root domain and redirection for /dir1/ redirects both domains to https://www.example.com/dir2/

Just couldn't find an answer on Stack Overflow and this being a heavy traffic live site I cannot afford to blow it up.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that `AllowOverwrite ALL` is enabled for both of the directories in your apache config.

```
<Directory /var/www/example.com>
        AllowOverride All
</Directory>
<Directory /var/www/example.com/sub1>
        AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

Once added, create `.htaccess` file in root of `example.com`

This will Redirect `example.com/dir1/` to `example.com/dir2/`

```
    RewriteEngine on
    Redirect 301 /dir1 http://example.com/dir2
```

Then, Create another `.htaccess` file inside subdirectory folder where wordpress is located.
This will Redirect `sub1.example.com/dir1/` to `sub1.example.com/dir2/`

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?dir1/(.*)$ /dir2/$1 [R,L]
```

After that,

```
sudo service apache2 restart
sudo a2enmod rewrite
```